# Angular: Searching fast results in canceled requests

Tags: angular, http, angular-httpclient

I have a search box for a list that makes HTTP requests to the server on text entry.

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="searchTextChange.next($event)">
```

This is how I'm handling it in my component file:

```
public searchTextChange = new Subject<string>();
this.searchTextChange.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe((text: string) => {
  let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.set('search', text);
  this.apiService.getList(params).subscribe((res) => {
   //..do something
  });
});
```

The problem I'm facing is with fast searching. The HTTP requests are getting canceled as I'm entering text fast. I tried giving a debounceTime of 500ms but that didn't help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to cancel the HTTP requests or you want to wait for every request before sending out the next request?

Comment: I am trying to wait for every request and don't want it to be canceled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concatMap` rxjs operator.
To understand how it works refer to this [RxJS Marbles site](https://rxmarbles.com/#concatMap)

All you would need to do is chain your request in following way

```
this.searchTextChange.pipe(concatMap(searchQuery => {
  let params = new HttpParams();
  params.set('search', searchQuery)
  return this.apiService.getResults(params);
})
.subscribe(results => console.log(results))
```

Refer to this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bals2o?file=src/app/app.module.ts)